# Chinese Remainder Theorem with sets of residues?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I've tried seeking this out in a few places and haven't come up with much that's useful.

(Edit: based on suggestion in the comments, I'm restricting the problem to coprime moduli. A restriction to only prime moduli might help more and would still be useful.)

The standard CRT gives one congruence for each modulus, and gives a unique answer modulo the product of the original moduli (for prime moduli). But what about a setup where you have a set of answers based on sets of congruences/residues? An example, where X is the set of results:

$$ x \in X \iff
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 0, 1, \text{or } 2 \pmod 5 \\
x \equiv 2, 4, \text{or } 6 \pmod 7 \\
x \equiv 3, 5, \text{or } 8 \pmod{11}
\end{cases}  $$

In this case, $$X = \{16, 25, 27, 30, 41, 60, 102, 107, 135, 137, 146, 151, 170, 181, 195,\\ 212, 247, 256, 261, 272, 291, 300, 305, 335, 366, 377, 382\}\pmod{385}$$

And of course the results set must have 27 members (3x3x3).

Are there any theorems or results for this sort of problem? Anything like:

- There must be some subset of solutions between M and N
- The [smallest/largest] solution must be [less than/greater than] M
- Certain patterns in the congruences create certain patterns in the results

Or am I barking up an unsolved/uninteresting/proven unsolvable tree?

Comment: @Will I see nothing in the OP indicating that they are considering noncoprime moduli (in fact "unique solutiom" implies coprime). so  you comment does not seem to be relevant.  Update: OP just edited it to explicitly specify coprime moduli.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by this... yes, a single value for each modulus gives a unique answer, but you're talking about enumerating the entire set of answers, which doesn't hit on what I'm looking at.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited the OP to indicate coprime moduli, a useful constraint and better to specify it than to leave it open.

Comment: There's not much that can be said in such generality. Sometimes these problems are solved by sieving, e.g. see the links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182616/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the link! Sadly the link to the Wooding thesis you link is expired. I'll see if I can find it elsewhere.  Edit: Found it! Not sure how to make a good link though. OK, [link here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-sieve-problem-in-one-and-two-dimensions-Wooding/f5319cab79f4a5c0e71c5c380bbcea169ccd8e83).

Comment: @Eric Happily you can search for it and locate it, and please update the link after doing so.

Comment: I think the Lehmer paper may well be my best start. @WillJagy, still entirely uncertain how you feel the Pinasco paper applies to this?

Comment: @Eric Yes, if you chase citations to the classic paper of Lehmer that I cited then you will likely locate more recent work iirc.