# Smallest number that satisfies set of modulo inequalities (incongruences?)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose I want to find the smallest $x$ that satisfies the following set of equations:

$$
\left(x+a_1\right)\mod{d_1} \not\equiv 0 \\
\left(x+a_2\right)\mod{d_2} \not\equiv 0 \\
\left(x+a_3\right)\mod{d_3} \not\equiv 0 \\
\vdots
$$

Is there a way to systematically do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yup,, look up Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: Generally sieving is one way to solve such problems, e.g. chase the links I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837864/chinese-remainder-theorem-with-sets-of-residues#comment7916178_3837864).