# Lehmer's bicycle chain sieve

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

I was reading about [Lehmer's bicycle chain sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_sieve) today. The underlying principle is outlined in this paper [Lehmer1928] by Lehmer.

While there are faster factoring methods available, the physical nature of Lehmer's method is fascinating.

I am trying to understand why this method is not suitable for factoring large integers.

**References:**

[Lehmer1928]: D. H. Lehmer (1928) The Mechanical Combination of Linear Forms, The American Mathematical Monthly, 35:3, 114-121, DOI: 10.1080/00029890.1928.11986799

Comment: The wikipedia article says that the machine was capable of effectively testing 5000 cases per second. That's peanuts to what computers can do.

Comment: Mind you, the machine was a marvel of its time (IIRC factoring was based on using quadratic residues to find potential factors). I once had the pleasure of attending a talk where Brillhart described its operation. It was just fascinating. Like when they replaced bicycle chains with films because the chains would start making figure 8 loops if you speeded up the crank too much.

Comment: You can find more info on the history and evolution of (sieve based) factoring machines in the thesis I cite [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182616/242).  See also  the citations in [Discovery of a lost factoring machine](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03024369)